# HTML Form elements reduces its height after form submission

Tags: html

I have designed a simple form to send me some data as feedback. The look of the form is same on all browser. But there is one problem I'm unable to fix. Whenever I submit the form the height of all the elements of my form get very much reduced. I even fixed the height of my elements but it is still getting decreased.!

This is the image before I submit the form.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtVbw.jpg

This is the image after submission. See the underlined text fields.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ3m9.jpg

Comment: What do you mean "after form submission"? While the browser is loading the page?

Comment: The images are very pretty, but its hard to diagnose the problem without seeing some code. But if you compare the HTML source of the two versions of the page, the problem is likely to show up quite quickly when you look at the code differences between them.

Comment: actually there is no code difference between them. And "after form submission" means that when I click on the submit button. Actully these are my php forms and its action page is reffered as PHP_SELF so it is a self submitting form. And when I click on submit button the page reloads with my text boxes and buttons minimined.

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's *View Source* feature to inspect the HTML. I bet you have some error or invalid elements before the `<DOCTYPE>`.